# Determine whether object has been finalized

Tags: python, garbage-collection, finalizer

One of the effects of the [GC changes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) that happened in Python 3.4 is that a gc-tracked object will only have its `__del__` method called once, even if the first `__del__` call resurrects the object:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __del__(self):
...         print('__del__')
...         global x
...         x = self
... 
>>> x = Foo()
>>> del x
__del__
>>> del x
>>>
```

(Untracked objects currently behave differently, since they don't have the flag that indicates already-finalized status. You can see this by inserting `__slots__ = ()` in the above class definition. I'm not sure whether whether this is a bug or a known and accepted behavior difference.)

For debugging purposes, it would be useful to be able to determine if an object has had its `__del__` method called. One option would be to insert a line in `__del__` that sets an indicator flag, but that requires advance preparation, and it may not be possible for objects with `__del__` written in C, such as generators.

Is it possible to determine whether an object has been finalized, without modifying its `__del__` method?

Comment: Has the documentation not been updated as of 3.6? Based on [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), it still seems like an implementation detail as to if `__del__` can be called twice.

Comment: Not quite sure when and how you intend on checking if the object has been finalized. Is checking if the variable still exists `'x' in globals()` not an option?

Comment: @user3483203: The PEP doesn't present it as an implementation detail, and it doesn't seem like it was *intended* to be one, but I guess it's documented as an implementation detail.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't seem intended to be one.  For example, in the [`gc` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage), they reference the PEP, not as an implementation detail.

Comment: @Gabriel: No. That doesn't distinguish between the state after `x = Foo()` and the state after the first `del x`. Also, it wouldn't generalize to other types even if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.9, this can be tested using `gc.is_finalized(obj)`.